# What's the advantage of adaptive IIR filter against FIR?

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response, adaptive-filters

Adaptive IIR filters is not straightforward, and may be unstable. Many people say that adaptive IIR filters *use less coefficients* than FIR filters. What I'm curious about is how many coefficients can IIR save?

I tried to use adaptive IIR filters to estimate transfer function of a 32-order FIR filter. Assume the IIR filter has $M+N+1$ coefficients: $a_1, a_2, ..., a_M, b_0, b_1, ...b_N$. I found the estimation result is acceptable only when $M+N+1 \ge 30$, i.e. only 2 coefficients can be saved.

In actual projects, for example, a 50 MHz FPGA, a 32-order FIR will produce about $(32 / 50 ~{M}) / 2 = 0.32 ~{\mu s}$ delay, so

- What will happen for IIR?
- Can adaptive IIR filters really reduce number of coefficients and reduce signal processing time delay?

Comment: Note that a typical 32 order FIR will produce about $16/50M = 0.32 \mu s $ delay: The dominant tap is usually in the center of the filter, causing the delay to be half of the filter length.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a 0.32 us delay. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Also do you mean to limit your question to adaptive filters specifically or is this a general question about IIR vs FIR filters (with fixed coefficients, therefore not adaptive)?

Comment: For adaptive ones, of course. I want to know, whether adaptive IIR filters is really useful, or it's just theoretically well-defined, but makes little difference in applications.

Comment: I am less familiar, will be interesting to hear.

Comment: I am also not familiar with adaptive IIR filters, but I am surprised and a little skeptical about it taking 31 adaptive IIR filter taps to match a 33 tap FIR filter.  Typically it would take far fewer IIR filter taps to produce a comparable filter.

Comment: @JimClay I considered it like this. For the simplest IIR filter, $\frac{1}{1+a z^{-1}}$, the Laurent series is $1 - a z^{-1} + a^2 z^{-2} - a^3 z^{-3} + \mathcal{O}(z^{-4})$. We can see in the expanded series, only 1 coefficient, $a$, is available. Consider a FIR filter $1 + b_1 z^{-1} + b_2 z^{-2} + b_3 z^{-3}$, it will be difficult for the Laurent series to approach the **FIR filter with more coefficients**. In this case, maybe IIR filters can't save taps to match a FIR filter.

Comment: I don't believe that that is a good way to compare the filters.  Instead, you should use metrics that are based on what you are probably actually trying to achieve, such as stop-band attenuation, ripple, etc.

Comment: I think your comparison is not fair, based on one example you can not conclude that saving from IIR is minor. Think of an impulse response with finite duration, say 4 samples. The IIR implementation in this case might be far less efficient but many other cases that impulse response shows exponential decay, IIR can model this signal a lot more efficiently.

Comment: Do you mean a normal IIR filter with *fixed* coefficients, or coefficients changing in time (the usual meaning of "adaptive filter") ?

Answer (score 7):

These are the key differences between FIR and IIR filters, regarding the feature you wish to control are the following:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{Feature} & \text{IIR} & \text{FIR} \\
\hline
\text{Implementation} & \text{Poles & Zeros} & \text{Zeros Only} \\
\text{States} & \text{Yes} & \text{No} \\
\text{Phase Delay} & \text{*} & \text{Half Integer} \\
\text{Stability} & \text{*} & \text{Always} \\
\text{Ripple} & \text{Yes} & \text{*} \\
\text{Cut-Off} & \text{Yes} & \text{*} \\
\end{array}
$$

The * indicates the feature can be controlled, by adding orders in most cases.

The standard definitions of FIR and IIR filters are:

FIR:

$$H(z)=b_0z^0+...+b_nz^n$$
$$y(t)=b_0u(t)+...+b_nu(t-n)$$

IIR:

$$H(z)=\frac{b_0+b_1z^1+...+b_nz^n}{1+a_1z^1+...+a_nz^n}$$
$$y(t)=b_0u(t)+...+b_nu(t-n)-a_1y(t-1)-...-a_ny(t-n)$$

$u$ is the input, $y$ is the output, $x$ is the states (below), $t$ is the time, scaled by a sampling time $dt$, $n$ is the number of orders of the filter. Each filter has $n$ size coefficient vectors, plus constant direct-output term $b_0$ (optional), and $a_0$=1. For simplicity assume $\sum{b_i}=1$ and $\sum{a_i}=1$, though this is not required anywhere.

**Implementation**. By definition, FIR include zeros only, leading to a [linear system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_filter) in the history vector for $u$: $[u(t-1)...u(t-n)]$.

IIR include both poles and zeros, also leading to a *linear system* in the history vector not only for $u$, but for $y$ too. Because of this, by one side IIR can be unstable; but by other side, they can be designed to have smooth ripple and sharp cutoffs with a minor number of orders.

**States**. FIR are *static systems* in the history vectors, meaning the filter is not dynamical, do not have states, is not recursive, no feedback.
IIR are *dynamical systems* in the history vectors, meaning the filters have states, is recursive, has feedback, hence have "memory" from past inputs & outputs.

**Phase Delay**. The [Phase Delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_delay_and_phase_delay) $\tau_\phi$

$$y(t)=y_0(t-\tau_t) sin(\omega(t-\tau_\phi)+\theta)$$

can be easily controlled in FIR implementations. 
If $b_k=b_{n-k}$,$k=0...n$, the phase delay is constant, equal to $n/2$ (the center of the FIR coefficients shape, its impulse response), equal to the group delay, and thus the filter become [linear phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_phase), with phase equal to $\omega\tau_phi$.

Because IIR have infinite impulse response, they can be [minimum phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_phase) instead of linear phase, though the phase achieved can be much less than the phase of a FIR for the same number of orders.

**Stability**. FIR are always stable, IIR can be designed to be stable, if stability is required.

**Ripple**. IIR can be designed to be flat-ripple both in pass-band|stop-band|both (butterworth|chebyshev|elliptic), FIR requires a major (tending to "infinite") number of orders for equate this property.

**Cut-Off**. IIR can be designed to have a sharp cut-off or narrow transition bands, FIR requires a major (tending to "infinite") number of orders for equate this property.

Related Articles:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-341-discrete-time-signal-processing-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec08.pdf
https://www.quora.com/Why-are-FIR-filters-preferred-over-IIR-filters
http://iowahills.com/A8FirIirDifferences.html
http://forums.prosoundweb.com/index.php?topic=2045.0
http://www.vyssotski.ch/BasicsOfInstrumentation/SpikeSorting/Design_of_FIR_Filters.pdf